# How can I see all the ENS domains owned by an eth address?

Tags: ethers.js, ens

I'm writing some code to obtain .eth domains of user using Raict, Rainbowkit and Wagmi and everything works fine, I can get owner wallet address, look up for additional data, but I can't read all domains attached to that owner.

Read documentation on this link: https://docs.ens.domains/dapp-developer-guide/resolving-names but can't find example of getting all domains.

You can check my ENS names register by me: https://etherscan.io/enslookup-search?search=0x9c82ec725db8dd4789427148b95e9a3ed1245154 . It shows 2 ENS names, but I can only get one, the primary kkatusic.eth.

Have someone example how to obtain all owner ENS domains?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

I have been going through this problem and the only way to do it without storing data to loop through is by using a 3rd party API. You can use [Alchemy](https://docs.alchemy.com/recipes/script-to-resolve-ens-domains-given-a-wallet-address), [Moralis](https://docs.moralis.io/reference/getwalletnfts) and maybe Infura (not fully sure about the last one). Alchemy already gives you the code to use and Moralis you would have to figure it out.

Comment: Thx, I will than try to use on that way ;)